# Setting a property by reflection with a string value

Tags: c#, reflection, type-conversion, propertyinfo, setvalue

I'd like to set a property of an object through Reflection, with a value of type `string`.
So, for instance, suppose I have a `Ship` class, with a property of `Latitude`, which is a `double`.

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
Ship ship = new Ship();
string value = "5.5";
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ship.GetType().GetProperty("Latitude");
propertyInfo.SetValue(ship, value, null);
```

As is, this throws an `ArgumentException`:

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Double'.

How can I convert value to the proper type, based on `propertyInfo`?

Comment: Question for you: is this part of a custom ORM solution?

Answer (score 596, accepted):

You can use [`Convert.ChangeType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130977.aspx) - It allows you to use runtime information on any `IConvertible` type to change representation formats. Not all conversions are possible, though, and you may need to write special case logic if you want to support conversions from types that are not `IConvertible`.

The corresponding code (without exception handling or special case logic) would be:

```
Ship ship = new Ship();
string value = "5.5";
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ship.GetType().GetProperty("Latitude");
propertyInfo.SetValue(ship, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

Comment: Review @AliKaraca answer below.  Both this and the one below are fast and loose but do the job for common types.

Comment: Is  there a `TryChangeType` or `CanChangeType`?

Answer (score 37):

As several others have said, you want to use `Convert.ChangeType`:

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(ship,
    Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType),
    null);
```

In fact, I recommend you look at the entire [`Convert` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx).

This class, and many other useful classes are part of the [`System` Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aspx). I find it useful to scan that namespace every year or so to see what features I've missed. Give it a try!

Comment: The OP probably wants the general answer, for setting a property of any type that has an obvious conversion from a string.

Comment: Good point. I'll edit and point to the real answerers, or will delete mine if someone will add what I said about the rest of the namespace.

Answer (score 29):

I tried the answer from **LBushkin** and it worked great, but it won't work for null values and nullable fields. So I've changed it to this:

```
propertyName= "Latitude";
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ship.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
if (propertyInfo != null)
{
     Type t = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfo.PropertyType) ?? propertyInfo.PropertyType;
     object safeValue = (value == null) ? null : Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
     propertyInfo.SetValue(ship, safeValue, null);
}
```

Comment: I have to say thank you as I met this case and this is the only one solution. thanks~!

Answer (score 20):

I notice a lot of people are recommending `Convert.ChangeType` - This does work for some cases however as soon as you start involving `nullable` types you will start receiving `InvalidCastExceptions`:

> http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/02/07/Convert.ChangeType-doesn_2700_t-handle-nullables.aspx

A wrapper was written a few years ago to handle this but that isn't perfect either.

> http://weblogs.asp.net/pjohnson/archive/2006/02/07/Convert.ChangeType-doesn_2700_t-handle-nullables.aspx

Answer (score 12):

You can use a type converter (no error checking):

```
Ship ship = new Ship();
string value = "5.5";
var property = ship.GetType().GetProperty("Latitude");
var convertedValue = property.Converter.ConvertFrom(value);
property.SetValue(self, convertedValue);
```

In terms of organizing the code, you could create a [kind-of mixin](http://codecrafter.blogspot.com/2010/02/c-quasi-mixins-pattern.html) that would result in code like this:

```
Ship ship = new Ship();
ship.SetPropertyAsString("Latitude", "5.5");
```

This would be achieved with this code:

```
public interface MPropertyAsStringSettable { }
public static class PropertyAsStringSettable {
  public static void SetPropertyAsString(
    this MPropertyAsStringSettable self, string propertyName, string value) {
    var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(self)[propertyName];
    var convertedValue = property.Converter.ConvertFrom(value);
    property.SetValue(self, convertedValue);
  }
}

public class Ship : MPropertyAsStringSettable {
  public double Latitude { get; set; }
  // ...
}
```

`MPropertyAsStringSettable` can be reused for many different classes.

You can also create your own custom [type converters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) to attach to your properties or classes:

```
public class Ship : MPropertyAsStringSettable {
  public Latitude Latitude { get; set; }
  // ...
}

[TypeConverter(typeof(LatitudeConverter))]
public class Latitude { ... }
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you added the marker insterface instead of just using `object`?

Comment: Yes, the marker interface serves as a placeholder to add the extension methods to. Using `object` would add the extension methods to all classes, which is not generally desirable.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably looking for the [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) method. For example:

```
Ship ship = new Ship();
string value = "5.5";
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ship.GetType().GetProperty("Latitude");
propertyInfo.SetValue(ship, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `Convert.ChangeType` and getting the type to convert from the `PropertyInfo.PropertyType`.

```
propertyInfo.SetValue( ship,
                       Convert.ChangeType( value, propertyInfo.PropertyType ),
                       null );
```

Answer (score 5):

I will answer this with a general answer. Usually these answers not working with guids. Here is a working version with guids too.

```
var stringVal="6e3ba183-89d9-e611-80c2-00155dcfb231"; // guid value as string to set
var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty("FooGuidProperty"); // property to be setted
var propType = prop.PropertyType;

// var will be type of guid here
var valWithRealType = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propType).ConvertFrom(stringVal);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It also works with GUIDs <3. Thanks, Ali (that's my daughter's nickname)

Comment: But still seems not to work with nullable types.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could try:

```
propertyInfo.SetValue(ship, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);

//But this will cause problems if your string value IsNullOrEmplty...
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing Metro app, you should use other code:

```
Ship ship = new Ship();
string value = "5.5";
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = ship.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("Latitude");
propertyInfo.SetValue(ship, Convert.ChangeType(value, propertyInfo.PropertyType));
```

Note:

```
ship.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty("Latitude");
```

instead of

```
ship.GetType().GetProperty("Latitude");
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code should solve your issue:

```
item.SetProperty(prop.Name, Convert.ChangeType(item.GetProperty(prop.Name).ToString().Trim(), prop.PropertyType));
```

Answer (score -11):

Are you looking to play around with Reflection or are you looking to build a production piece of software?  I would question why you're using reflection to set a property.

```
Double new_latitude;

Double.TryParse (value, out new_latitude);
ship.Latitude = new_latitude;
```

Comment: You should respect what people attempt to do and not what you think they must do. Downvoted. (From `GenericProgramming.exe:ReflectionBenefits()` )

Comment: Er, perhaps because you don't know what the Property is beforehand, and while it's typed the value you're using is always a string? This is my case: I'm screen scraping HTML, so the value I get is always a string, and which properties I want and how to find them are defined in a config file, so Reflection is the only reasonable way to do it.