# How to set object property through Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to code a method that will accept the following 3 arguments:

1. an Object (user defined type which will vary)
2. a string representing a property name for that object
3. a string value, which will have to be converted from a string to the property's data type prior to assignment.

The method signature will look like this:

```
public void UpdateProperty(Object obj, string propertyName, string value)
```

I've found how to retrieve a property value with Reflection with the following code:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = target.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

  foreach (PropertyInfo prop in properties)
  {
    if (string.Compare(prop.Name, propertyName, true) == 0)
    {
      return prop.GetValue(target, null).ToString();
    }
  }
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to set the property value.  Also, the value is coming in as a string, so I have to check the data type of the value against the property's datatype before it can be cast & assigned.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/net-reflection-set-object-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx) with [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08.aspx) should work for you.  Using your code:

```
newValue = Convert.ChangeType(givenValue, prop.PropertyType);
prop.SetValue(target, newValue, null);
```

Comment: Austin, You're the MAN! This worked great.  I used var as the type declaration for newValue ( newValue = Convert.ChangeType(givenValue, prop.PropertyType);)

Answer (score 1):

SetValue is what you are looking for.

There are plenty of questions on here with sample code (take a look at the Related Question list on the right of this page)

e.g. [Setting a property by reflection with a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/c-setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value)

Answer (score 1):

```
prop.SetValue(target,new TypeConverter().ConvertFromString(propertyValue));
```

Comment: This didn't compile for me without a third argument (null) and then it errored with "TypeConverter cannot convert from System.String."  I'm not sure.  In either case I need to attempt conversion to a specific datatype (prop.PropertyType).