# C# dynamically set property

Tags: c#, methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net - Reflection set object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619767/net-reflection-set-object-property)
>   [Setting a property by reflection with a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value)

I have an object with multiple properties. Let's call the object objName. I'm trying to create a method that simply updates the object with the new property values.

I want to be able to do the following in a method:

```
private void SetObjectProperty(string propertyName, string value, ref object objName)
{
    //some processing on the rest of the code to make sure we actually want to set this value.
    objName.propertyName = value
}
```

and finally, the call:

```
SetObjectProperty("nameOfProperty", textBoxValue.Text, ref objName);
```

Hope the question is fleshed out enough. Let me know if you need more details.

Thanks for the answers all!

Comment: @DavidArcher there is no `rel` keyboard in C#...I take it you mean `ref`? There is no need to pass an object as `ref` unless you intend on changing the actual instance of it.

Comment: Indeed, I did mean ref, and yes, I do intend on changing the actual instance.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`objName.GetType().GetProperty("nameOfProperty").SetValue(objName, objValue, null)`

Comment: You should use `propertyName` inside `GetProperty()`.

Comment: And what if "*nameOfProperty*" doesn't exist?

Comment: Exception of course, you can use GetProperties to test.

Comment: I was able to replace my 200 line code with 5 lines using your code sample. Thanks, you saved my day.

Answer (score 47):

You can use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to do this e.g.

```
private void SetObjectProperty(string propertyName, string value, object obj)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    // make sure object has the property we are after
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Props for checking for null before calling.

Comment: I usually also check for "can write": `if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.CanWrite)`.

Comment: How if I want to set static property Sir?

Answer (score 4):

Get the property info first, and then set the value on the property:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = objName.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
propertyInfo.SetValue(objName, value, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Type.InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember.aspx) to do this.

```
private void SetObjectProperty(string propertyName, string value, rel objName) 
{ 
    objName.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, 
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, 
        Type.DefaultBinder, objName, value); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via reflection:

```
void SetObjectProperty(object theObject, string propertyName, object value)
{
  Type type=theObject.GetType();
  var property=type.GetProperty(propertyName);
  var setter=property.SetMethod();
  setter.Invoke(theObject, new ojbject[]{value});
}
```

NOTE: Error handling intentionally left out for the sake of readability.