# How to update Object Class with key c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I'm struggling in updating an object with the given key only.

right now i can update using this:

```
public class Person {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Highest {get;set;}
    public ..... (so many more)
}
```

this is what im using.

```
var model = db.Person.Find(1);
model.Highest = "20 meters";
```

what i want for it is to behave like an array where i will only update the data based on key like:

```
 var key = "Highest";
 var model = db.Person.Find(1);
 model[key] = "20 meters";
```

so that i can use it as a function

```
public Person UpdateData(Person model,string key,string newvalue){
 model[key] = newvalue;
 return model;
}
```

im think of converting it to array first then update then convert back to object. but i cant find a way to convert it into array.

do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It is possible to do this using reflection API. But if you need to do this in a tight, performance heavy loop, it will suffer. Why do you need to do this in the first place? What happens if the new value is not string?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why? You're working with objects, not dictionaries. These are properties, not keys. If you don't want to use strongly-typed objects, don't use an ORM. It would be easier to use a DataTable

Comment: Why are you trying to set properties by name? It matters

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `dynamic` feature of C# to lookup properties by key, or through Reflection API similar to this answer [C# dynamically set property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970353/c-sharp-dynamically-set-property).

But beware of type safety and runtime errors that could happen due to incompatible types.

Probably in your case the best bet is to use an Object Mapper library like [automapper](https://automapper.org/).

Comment: i need in my other code the regular class, i think if i declare it as dynamic then it will be all the way dynamic, unless 
1. i convert the regular class into dynamic.
2. update the data.
3. convert back to regular class.

is this what you mean? if so, i dont know how to convert the class into dynamic.

Comment: @Darvin why are you trying to set the properties by name in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `UpdateData` method so it uses reflection. I would drop the idea with the indexer (`model[key]`).

```
    public static Person UpdateData(Person model, string key, string newvalue)
    {
        model.GetType().GetProperty(key).SetValue(model, newvalue);
        return model;
    }
```

However, if you really want use indexer you can do something like this in your `Person`:

```
    public object this[string propName]
    {
        get => this.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(this);
        set => this.GetType().GetProperty(propName).SetValue(this, value);
    }
```

Then you could use it like this `person["Highest"] = "45";`, but I don't really recommend this approach.

Comment: Thank you, i found  this one and planning to close the thread, but yours is shorter,

`
private void SetObjectProperty(string propertyName, string value, object obj)
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    // make sure object has the property we are after
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, value, null);
    }
}
`

from the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12970353/c-sharp-dynamically-set-property)