# dynamically work with different classes

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a class:

```
 public class Test1
 {
     public void assignData(List<CustomClass> customData, string targetFieldName)
     {             
         for(int i=0; i<customData.Count; i++)
         {
             if(customData[i].targetFieldName)
             {
                 customData[i].targetFieldName = newValue;
             }   
         }
     }
 }

 List<customClass1> list1;
 List<customClass2> list2;
```

customClass1 and customClass2 are completely different, but they share the same field 'dateAdded'. I want to be able to call Test1.assignData(list1, "dateAdded") and Test1.assignData(list2, "dateAdded"). and the list1 and list2 will get updated. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: do customclass1 and 2 derive from customclass ?

Comment: If you really want to let go of strong typing and pass a property name to assign, then I think you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have a common interface that they both implement which exposes the `dateAdded` field as a property

```
interface ICustomClass {
  DateTime dateAdded { get; set; }
}
```

Then both classes can implement that interface and you can change the function to use that interface

```
public void assignData(IEnumerable<ICustomClass> enumerable) {
  foreach (var customData in enumerable) {
    customData.dateAdded = newValue;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
In the comments the OP stated their desire to make this update to any list irrespective of the interface.  In that case the likely best course is to use `dynamic`

```
public void assignData(IEnumerable<object> enumerable) {
  foreach (dynamic customData in enumerable) {
    try { 
      customData.dateAdded = newValue;
    } catch { 
      // Object doesn't have dateAdded so just move on
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I just want to read it I still have to implement the interface? is there a way of doing it without?

Comment: @user2320462 you can always use `dynamic` or reflection to avoid an interface. In general though I would avoid them unless there was a compelling reason and start with an interface

Comment: @user2320462: you can just have a `get` accessor in your interface.

Comment: @JaredPar I want to be able to alter any list, so that I don't have to make any adjustments to target list class, just any list that has dateAdded field in it, should be updated

Comment: @user2320462 then your best choice in that case is to use `dynamic`.  I'll update with a sample

Comment: Where is `newValue` coming from - missing parameter?

Comment: @DerekW unknown, the original question just has `newValue` without any context.  I just assumed it was a field the OP omitted from the question

Answer (score 1):

If `CustomClass1` and `CustomClass2`both deriving from `CustomClass` and you want to simply set value of `targetFieldName` , all you need to do is replace `List<T>` with `IEnumerable<T>`.

Make sure the common field is in base class so that it can be accessed without worrying about the derived implementation.

```
public void assignData(List<CustomClass> customData, string targetFieldName)
```

with

```
public void assignData(IEnumerable<CustomClass> customData,
                                                string targetFieldName)
```

With this you can call it for both lists because of `covariance`. Simple example -

```
IEnumerable<object> list = new List<string>(); // This will work

List<object> list = new List<string>(); // This won't compile.
```

Answer (score 1):

So I totally agree with @JaredPar that this sounds like you need a common interface but it is possible with dynamics.

Note that this example code doesn't behave properly if DateAdded isn't  present

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace dynamics_test
{
    class CustomOne
    {
        public string NotInCustomTwo { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }

    class CustomTwo
    {
        public string NotInCustomOne { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }


    [TestFixture]
    public class TestDynamics
    {
        private List<CustomOne> _customOnes;
        private List<CustomTwo> _customTwos;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            this._customOnes = new List<CustomOne>()
                {
                    new CustomOne {DateAdded = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), NotInCustomTwo = "some value"},
                    new CustomOne {DateAdded = DateTime.Now, NotInCustomTwo = "some value"}
                };
            this._customTwos = new List<CustomTwo>()
                {
                    new CustomTwo {DateAdded = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), NotInCustomOne = "some value"},
                    new CustomTwo {DateAdded = DateTime.Now, NotInCustomOne = "some value"}
                };
        }

        [Test]
        public void DynamicsAllowBadThingsMkay()
        {
            var dynamics = _customOnes.Cast<dynamic>().ToList();
            dynamics.AddRange(_customTwos);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, dynamics.Count(d=>d.DateAdded.Date == DateTime.Now.Date));
            foreach (var thing in dynamics)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(thing.DateAdded);
            }
        }
    }
}
```