# create new property typeof generics T in c#

Tags: c#, generics

i have a function like this, it get a typeof T, cipher the properties(all properties are string):

```
private T Cipher(T item)
    {
        var t = item.GetType();
        //get all properties of item and put in a list 
        var props=new List<PropertyInfo>(t.GetProperties());
        var vals= props.Select(propertyInfo =>
                               propertyInfo.GetValue(item).ToString()).ToList();
        var cipher = new List<string>();
        foreach (var val in vals)
        {
            cipher.Add(CipherString.Encrypt(val,"key");
        }
```

is there any way to create a new typeof T property with new values of         `cipher`? 
Edit: T is class definition with some properties

Comment: Setting property by reflection
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value
Create instance :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After getting properties but instead of getting values you can do this

```
var ciphered = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
foreach (var property in props)
    property.SetValue(ciphered, CipherString.Encrypt(property.GetValue(item, null) as string, "key"));
return ciphered;
```

Comment: in var ciphered = Activator.CreateInstance<T>(); System.MissingMethodException occures!

Comment: This method was introduced in .NET framework 3.5 (if I'm correct). If you are using version prior to this you can use code `var ciphered = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) as T;`

Comment: I'm using .NET framework 4.5 and that exception occured again!! and thnks

Comment: @AliTheOne: Do you have a parameterless constructor in your T-class?

Comment: No, i found the answer:because my class type doesn't define in .Net so i should use this :'FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(T.GetType());' instead  of Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)) thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try use conversion like (T)(Object). Example.

```
 private T SomeFunction(T arg)
 {
        var cipher = new List<string>();
        cipher.Add("Test");
        cipher.Add("Test 2");
        cipher.Add("Test 3");
        return (T)(Object)cipher;
 }
```

Sample

```
class Test<T> where T: IEnumerable<string>, ICollection<string>
{
    public T Copy(T src)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var s in src as ICollection<string>)
            result.Add(s);
        return (T)(Object)result;
    }

    public void Print(T what)
    {
        foreach (var s in what as ICollection<string>)
            Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////   

Test<List<string>> t = new Test<List<string>>();
t.Print(t.Copy(new List<string>() { "One", "Two" }));
```

Comment: There is no conversion between List<string> and generic T types so you'll get InvalidCastException

Comment: for some reason you suggest that the class T is a collection of strings. But the asker want to get all the properties of T object and not its contents