# It seems that Type.InvokeMember does not work with short,int16 or other 16bit numeric type of class

Tags: c#, reflection, invokemember

```
public class Test{
    public string name{get;set}
    public short age{get;set;}
}
```

....

```
var type = typeof(Test);

var ins = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

type.InvokeMember("name", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null,   ins ,new object[] { "alibaba" });

type.InvokeMember("age", BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.SuppressChangeType, null, ins ,new object[] { 2 });
```

...

An exception of method 'age' not found throw when running,if I change the type of 'age' to int or other 32+ numeric type, it works

Whether or not the InvokeMember does not support type of short,int16 ect. Or I might change another way to assign value.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are passing an `int` to the `InvokeMember()` method. I'm sure if you passed a value of the correct type, e.g. `short`, it would work.

Comment: public string aPropery { get; set; } is a property. public string aMember = "aValue";   is called a member or a field.

Comment: @PeterDuniho yes, you are right,I must use a type convert (short)2,so that the InvokeMember() works correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this.  It worked for me.

```
//credit to stack overflow post and the following post
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value

Test test = new Test();
PropertyInfo property = typeof(Test).GetProperty("name");
property.SetValue(test, "NameValue", null);
PropertyInfo propertyTwo = typeof(Test).GetProperty("age");
short aShort = 49;
propertyTwo.SetValue(test, aShort, null);
```