# c# set variable value based on string

Tags: c#

I have a class with a list of variables (shortened to one "a" here) -  I'm trying to create a way to populate a variable based on two string inputs, so I can just use, for instance:

```
SET_VAL("a", "value_for_a")
```

Which I'd like to get the MessageBox showing just "value_for_a"

but I'm tripping up trying to use reflection, I'm sure this is possible, I know it's possible to get a value from a variable using a string to find it's name, cos every time I search for this that's all I seem to get, but why doesn't the following work? The method `SetValue` is asking for objects as parameters when I just want to pass two strings?

```
public class MySystem_SubsNote
   {
       public string a;

       public void SET_VAL(string mytype, string myvalue)
       {
            this.GetType().GetField(mytype).SetValue(myvalue);
            MessageBox.Show(a);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Why not just have a `Dictionary<string,string>` rather than any specific variables?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Fix that first please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a property by reflection with a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value)

Comment: "It's asking for objects as parameters :/" Can you elaborate? Where do you get this error? And what is the exact error?

Comment: `FieldInfo.SetValue` requires 2 parameters, the instance on which to set the field and the value, you're only passing the value. Try `.SetValue(this, myvalue);`

Comment: When saying "it doesn't work", tell us why you think so, if you get an error message, post the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned from Lasse in the comments `SetValue` expects *two* parameters, the first being the instance of which to set the value, the second the new value. So this should do it:

```
public void SET_VAL(string mytype, string myvalue)
{
    this.GetType().GetField(mytype).SetValue(this, myvalue);
    MessageBox.Show(a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense but now I'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` on this line. I don't understand since I've set an instance of it in another method, and am using `this` - when highlighted - `this` shows the object/class type

Comment: then I suppose `GetField` does return `null`. Maybe you have a typo in your field-name?

Comment: I just recreated this as a mini-project and it worked fine so I think there may be a hidden space in my field-name on my large project (it's parsed separately from a huge string list) - thanks for the advice, marking this as best answer since it definitely works!

Comment: Just FYI it wasn't the field that was an issue, I had replaced "GetField" with "GetProperty" while I was trying different things and forgot to change it back :/