# Set and get value of the Nested Class by string without class name

Tags: c#, class, reflection, properties

I have a lot of txt file, that contains a lot of datas. For example:

```
1.txt
parameter1_1="[1 3 21 12 42]"
parameter2_1="[4 2 28 72 46]"
parameter2_2="[2 6 46 75 76]"
58.txt
parameter1_1="[9 8 98 87 89]"
parameter1_2="[2 4 11 42 62]"
parameter2_1="[9 4 25 67 56]"
parameter2_2="[7 6 87 79 75]"
```

In the first txt file all of the parameter's first value is a coil datas. The second value is the second coil datas.
I want to put all of the value into one class/object what is contains all of the value`like you can see on the picture.

[image]

When I upload the object, the index cannot be slip, so if I choose the index 1 from teh collection, then I get the correct datas.

I created a class  as you can see, and I cannot get the nested class property by string.

I have the next class

```
    public class Coil
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class FailStation : Coil
{
    public Station_1 Station_1 = new Station_1();
    public Station_2 Station_2 = new Station_2();
}

public class Station_1
{
    public string parameter1_1{ get; set; }
    public string parameter1_2 { get; set; }
}
public class Station_2
{
    public string parameter2_1{ get; set; }
    public string parameter2_2 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to set and get the value like this or something simiar:

```
FailStationcoil coil = new FailStation();
List<FailStation> AllCoil = new List<FailStation>();
coil["parameter1_1"] = "value"; //or
coil.SetPropValue("parameter1_1", "value");
coil["ID"]="1";
AllCoil.Add(coil);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a property by reflection with a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089123/setting-a-property-by-reflection-with-a-string-value)

Comment: Have you considered using a simple `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of nested classes with properties?

Comment: @obl That one is not a nested class.

Comment: @Fildor Now the program work with Dictionary, but it's not really dynamic.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? Could you explain what your actual goal behind all this is?

Comment: @Alex Please explain why it matters that these are nested classes. What is `coildata`? Is it an object of type `Coil`? `Station_101`? Are you trying to set a property of type `string` or `object`?

Comment: @obl I exlained better. Please read it.

Comment: @Fildor I want to set value by string and not for example coil.Station_1.parameter2_1=value, because I have more then 100 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your parameter names already tell you what `Station` it is, unless I'm misreading it.

`parameter1_1 =>` the first number tells you `Station_{n}`, the second number tells you `cam_term_{n}_val`

So why not ditch the `Station_1` and `Station_2` classes and just use a `Dictionary<string, int>` or `Dictionary<string, object>` (if you need to store the keys with no value) as @Fildor suggested?

Reflection is expensive and should only be used if absolutely necessary. Your situation, as you have explained so far, doesn't look like it requires it.

Comment: Yes in the example the name is similar, but in the real life, where I want to you I don't know the station name from the parameter name, because it's different. Please check the picture. If the reflection is expensive, then how can I link the parameter name to the station? Could you suggest a good method?

Comment: @Alex please update your code to show how you are reading in the text files. I don't understand what you mean by the station name and parameter name being different. How then do you know which properties go to which station?